# Using rbreak without import functions

Tags: debugging, linux, gdb, breakpoint

While debugging  with GDB I want to break for each function and print the PC register.

```
rbreak .
define hook-stop
   i r $PC
   c
end
```

The problem is that is stop on functions that imported like `printf` and `memcpy` .

How can I stop only on functions in my binary that not imported?

Comment: What definition of 'function' are you using?  Does it need to be something you're exporting?  if you use `readelf -s <target>` does the symbol table contain the functions you want to find, or are you just looking for anything reached by a 'call' instruction during execution?  (I ask because the optimizer can do funny things to functions, including merging the tail of several similar functions into a single set of instructions shared by all.)

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b I looking for all the function that implement in my binary.